# Error: Special characters are not uploaded from csv to database in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay-6

I am inserting records from csv file to mysql database in Liferay 6.1. I have already set porta-ext.properties file with

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root jdbc.default.password=root
```

when I am trying to upload records ,it throws error for special characters like á 
Error details:

```
13:38:21,001 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:75] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'providerName' at row 1
```

When I removed those characters it persists records without error.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your database is in UTF-8 and you have "special" characters in it than most probably you are missing "file.encoding=UTF-8" vm argument (-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8), or at least you should specify encoding when opening file/stream.

Comment: Retrieving from file is not a issue because it is retrieving from csv file and printing on console without any error. I am storing records into List then I am storing into database. Error generats at Persistence layer. UTF-8 character is directly stored into MySql without any error. Problem is in storing through Liferay Service Builder into MySql.

Comment: Can you, for test, for providerName enter just one "special" character (remove the rest) and see what happens (on all csv lines or try with just one line in csv). Also please show complete (or relevant portion of)  stacktrace when you get error.

Comment: I have entered café in csv file and then uploaded it throws following errors :                                                  08:54:13,796 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter:75] Data truncation: Data too long for column 'providerName' at row 1
08:54:13,812 ERROR [Admin:812] caf∩┐╜

Comment: What is defined length of 'providerName' column?

Comment: Length of providerName is longtext in MySql